# Fragment Custom Object Animator After Android Version 6 - Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, android-animation

I have custom object animator for my fragment transitions.There is no problem with animations before Android version 6 (Marshmallow). But after 6, my fragments during animation overlapping each other like below

[image]

My custom animator for left sliding is

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="1000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

 </set>
```

To create fragment with animation :

```
    Fragment fr = new GameSizeFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(activeFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlace, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Can someone help me, why it is causing problem after version 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Fragment usage as android.support.v4.app instead of android.app and it looks like problem solved.Instead of using object animator you must use the anims with support v4

**enter from right anim**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="500"
       android:fromXDelta="100%"
       android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

**enter to right anim**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="500"
       android:fromXDelta="0%"
       android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

Then create your fragmet

```
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fr = new YourFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(activeFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlace, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```